# Projective deformations of a projective hyperkahler manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X$ be a projective hyperkahler manifold, $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ its Kuranishi family. We define $\mathcal{P}:=\{m\in \mathcal{M} $such that $\mathcal{X}_m$ is projective$\}$, where of course $\mathcal{X}_m=f^{-1}(m)$.

I've read in a paper by Arnaud Beauville that $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{M}_h$ where $\mathcal{M}_h:=\{m\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $P_X(m) \perp h\}$ where $P_X$ is the period map, the orthogonality is with respect to the Bogomolov form on $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ and $h$ is the class of a hyperplane section.

I hope i'm not missing something fundamental, but i can't understand why is $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{M}_h$.

Given $u:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow X\times \mathcal{M}$, it seems like if $\mathcal{X}_m$ is not projective then $u_m^*$ sends $h$ in something that is not in $H^{1,1}(\mathcal{X}_m)$, but why...